# How to take specific data from table and store it in a cookie codeigniter php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and php, few days only, so I need a little help.
I'm trying to put some data in my cookie from table so I can check where to redirect user after login. In table `users` there are two columns named `Admin` and `Company` with one or zero if user is or not, and then i wish to insert that information to cookie.

function conformation in user_controler is:

```
function conformation(){
    $this->load->model('user');
    $q = $this->user->confr();
    if($q){
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'Admin' => $this->input->post($a = $this->user->getAdmin), // get 1/0 from users column Admin 
            'Company' => $this->input->post($c = $this->user->getComp),            
            'login' => true
        );
        if( $a == 1 ){ //is admin redirect to admin view 
           $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('user_controler/useradm');
        }
        if($c == 1){ //if company redirect to company view
          $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('user_controler/usercomp');
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);// if common user redirect to user view
        redirect('user_controler/userpro');
    }
    else{ // if nothing above redirect to login page
        redirect('user_controler/log');
    }
}
```

And in user model:

```
function getAdmin{
   $this->db->where('Admin', 1);
   $a = $this->db->get('users');
}
function getComp{
   $this->db->where('Company', 1);
   $a = $this->db->get('users');
}
function conf(){
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
        $q = $this->db->get('users');

        if($q->num_rows == 1 ){
            return TRUE;                
        }
    }
```

Also have site controller for checking login

```
class Site extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->login();
    }

    function login(){
        $login = $this->session->userdata('login');

        if(!isset($login) || login != TRUE){
            $this->log;
            die();
        }
    }

}
```

Of course it's not working because i should probably check these column some other way but I don't know how. I Also have enabled table `ci_session` and it's work perfectly without `Admin` and `Company`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Here are my updates to the code (I have annotated my changes):

```
function conformation(){
    $this->load->model('user');

    if($this->user->confr()){  //$q wasn't needed, as you are only using this twice
        $user = $this->input->post('username');  //I have added this as I will be referring to it a couple of times.
        $data = array(
            'username' => $user,
            'Admin' => $this->user->getAdmin($user), // Your method was questioning the original form looking for data that it would never find - This will question your model.
            'Company' => $this->user->getComp($user), //Same as above            
            'login' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);  //It doesn't matter who the user is, we shall set the data to start with.
        if($this->user->getAdmin($user)){ //is admin redirect to admin view 
           redirect('user_controler/useradm');
        }
        elseif($this->user->getComp($user)){ //if company redirect to company view
            redirect('user_controler/usercomp');
        }
        else { //Redirect non-privileged users.
            redirect('user_controler/userpro');
        }
    }
    else{ // if nothing above redirect to login page
        redirect('user_controler/log');
    }
}
```

Users Model:

```
function getAdmin($user){
   $this->db->where('username', $user); //Before you was just returning everyone who is an admin   This instead finds the user
   $a = $this->db->get('users');

   foreach($a as $u) {
       if($u["Admin"]==1) { return true; }  //This finds if the user is a admin or not, and the function will now return a value (true)
   }
}
function getComp($user) {
   $this->db->where('username', $user); 
   $a = $this->db->get('users');

   foreach($a as $u) {
       if($u["Company"]==1) { return true; }
   }
}  //Edited similar to the function above
function conf(){
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $q = $this->db->get('users');

    if($q->num_rows == 1 ){
        return TRUE;                
    }
}
```

Lastly your login function:

```
function login(){
    $login = $this->session->userdata('login');

    if(!isset($login) || $login != TRUE){  //You weren't referring to your $login variable
        $this->log;
        die();
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps with your problems, let me know if you need any amendments.

Comment: Thank you for code and annotation, now it's working but only redirect to non-privileged users, it's like that it doesn't check admin or company but always go tu non-privileges user... the columns are tinyint(1) maybe because of this.. this is what it's store in session table:                                                   a:5:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:6:"username";s:5:"sanja";s:5:"Admin";N;s:9:"Company";N;s:8:"login";b:1;} and it should be because sanja is admin b:1 and redirect ta admin page

Comment: That would look as if your "Admin" value is `N` or `Y` rather than `0` or `1` as stated in your question?  

Please note a `int` or `tinyint` should refer to a number, so my recommendation would be to change these values to a `1` or `0`.

Otherwise change `if($u["Admin"]==1)` to `if($u["Admin"]=="Y")` and then `if($u["Company"]==1)` to `if($u["Company"]=="Y")` and change your data types in the database.  _If this answer does solve your problem please mark it as the correct answer please_

Comment: at the end i didn't manage to solve the problem that way because however i change something in base everyone get redirected to the same page... it's tinyint(1) and value is 0 or 1 but still... Solved problem with creating new table Admin and Company and instead foreach put if($k->num_rows >0){ return TRUE; } and get new table.... Thanks you very much Daniel, without you, couldn't manage to solve this so thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to work out how to solve it. Thanks, if you get any other problems stackoverflow is a great site and someone has usually had experience of the same problem you've had.